# Safecopy migrating from string to bytestring

Tags: haskell, bytestring

I am trying to use the [safecopy](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/safecopy) haskell library, but when I try to migrate a string to a bytestring, the last 4 characters are lost and 4 '\NULL' characters get prepended to the string:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell, DeriveDataTypeable, TypeFamilies #-}
import Data.SafeCopy
import Data.Acid
import Data.Typeable
import Control.Monad.State.Class
import Control.Monad.Reader.Class

data T = T { str :: String }
         deriving (Show, Typeable)

getT :: Query T String
getT = fmap str ask

setT :: String -> Update T ()
setT str = put $ T str

deriveSafeCopy 0 'base  ''T

makeAcidic ''T ['setT, 'getT]

main :: IO ()
main = do
  state <- openLocalState (T "string set with default")
  update state (SetT "string set with SetT")
  str <- query state GetT
  putStrLn str
```

This outputs: `string set with SetT`, but when you run the following modificated version after that:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell, DeriveDataTypeable, TypeFamilies #-}
import Data.SafeCopy
import Data.Acid
import Data.Typeable
import Control.Monad.State.Class
import Control.Monad.Reader.Class
import Data.ByteString.Char8 as B

data T_v0 = T_v0 String
         deriving (Show, Typeable)
deriveSafeCopy 0 'base  ''T_v0

data T = T { str :: B.ByteString }
         deriving (Show, Typeable)
deriveSafeCopy 1 'extension ''T

instance Migrate T where
  type MigrateFrom T = T_v0
  migrate (T_v0 str) = T $ B.pack str

getT :: Query T B.ByteString
getT = fmap str ask

setT :: B.ByteString -> Update T ()
setT str = put $ T str
makeAcidic ''T ['setT, 'getT]

main :: IO ()
main = do
  state <- openLocalState (T $ B.pack "bytestring set with default")
  str <- query state GetT
  print str
```

it outputs: `"\NUL\NUL\NUL\NULstring set with "`. I have no idea why this is happening. Am I doing something wrong in the migration step? I have tried to stay as close as possible to the [example code](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/safecopy-0.8.5/docs/Data-SafeCopy.html). Does anyone know why this is happening?

P.S: Sorry for the big amount of code, but I couldn't think of any better way to convey the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of `acid-state`. You've changed the types of `getT` and `setT` between the implementations which messes up the transaction log. You essentially cannot change any functions you've tagged with `makeAcidic` without first clearing the transaction log with [`createCheckpoint`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/acid-state-0.12.4/docs/Data-Acid.html#v:createCheckpoint) (using the older version of the codebase).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I hadn't thought of it being a problem with acid-state.